# Исполнение скрипта Python на github.io

Tags: python, сервер, github

Имеется серверный скрипт на Python и хостинг на github.io. При загрузке скрипта на github.io и последующем открытии его через браузер, скрипт скачивается, а не выполняется. Как сделать так, что бы скрипт выполнялся?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак - это невозможно. Скрипт выполняется интерпретатором, интерпретатор - это такой же бинарник, как и все остальные. github.io не позволяет никак этот интерпретатор запустить - он только отдает клиенту (браузеру) только то, что находится в вашем репозитории. Браузером .py файлы воспринимаются как текст (и открывается как текст) или как multipart данные и скачивается как файл.

Если вы хотите какой-никакой интерактивности на странице - есть разные движки для статических сайтов (и Github Pages хостит именно статические сайты), которые берут на себя заботу о сохранении и загрузке информации из статических файлов. [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), например.